# How to change default system updates folder in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: installation, updates, root, ram, stable-release-updates

Hi I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 15r (dual booting with Windows 8). During installation, I had set aside 6GB for my root folder, 8GB for swap and about 20+ GB (don't remember exact figure) for my Home folder which ic currently largely empty. Recently, I have been receiving consistent system alerts stating that I am running out of disk memory for installing further system updates. How is this possible? Are my updates being installed in my "root" instead of "home". How can I fix this? Thanks in advance :)

I use BleachBit to clean memory time-to-time. However, I keep receiving these updates which eat up all the space and give the low-memory warning even though I have 20+GB memory space in my home folder! How can I manage this?

Is it safe to delete old kernel modules? How can I locate and remove packages that are no longer needed or not being used?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your downloads are going to your root or even your boot.
Run Bleachbit both as user and root.Check everything so it will clean out everything.
It should free up lots of space for you.
As to your downloads right click on a download and choose to open up the download folder. Now examine it to see where it is located so you will know where they are going. Change the downloads folder to where yo want it to be.
Also open Synaptic, go to Settings then Preferences. Click on the Files tab and check Delete downloaded packages after installation. This will clear up the download cache and make space for you.

Comment: Hey thanks for all the tips !! Could you also answer my most recent edit??